# Having issues scraping the image from a website using bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hey I can't seem to scrape the images from this website

```
https://www.nike.com/gb/w/new-mens-shoes-3n82yznik1zy7ok
```

I am using the following code

```
product.find('img', {'class': 'css-1fxh5tw product-card__hero-image'})['src']]
```

It returns this

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
```

Comment: That is actually the content of the `src` attribute of that image. I guess there is some javascript on the page which uses that to load the image, based on that value. You should find out what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was not wrong. I have extracted images

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ="https://www.nike.com/gb/w/new-mens-shoes-3n82yznik1zy7ok"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

images = soup.find_all('img', {'class':'css-1fxh5tw product-card__hero-image'},src=True)
for i in images:
    if 'data:image' not in i['src']:
        print(i['src'])
```